# Trasitioning li to width of contained text

Tags: css, overflow, css-transitions

I wonder if anybody has any examples to achieve what I'm looking for. I would like the tabs to have a fixed width when they aren't selected - however, on hover/focus/select then they would be the width of the containing text.

Image of what I'm trying to achieve:

https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-QrJnScR01yo/UjLE44u2qdI/AAAAAAAAFv0/qWaOY-hihk8/w887-h286-no/mockup.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transition `max-width` from your fixed value to a reasonably high number, say, 1000 or 3000 px, but it creates a delay after mouseleave:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tgJhz

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
    <li>Lorem.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Non-relevant CSS */
ul
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li
{
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid #000;

  white-space: nowrap;
  /* text-overflow: ellipsis; */
  overflow: hidden;

  cursor: pointer;
}
li+li { border-left: none; }

/* Relevant CSS */
li
{
  -webkit-transition: max-width 1s;
  max-width: 50px;
}
li:hover
{
  max-width: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: Please always include the code to make your answer self-contained.

Comment: Thank you for your help! The codepen solution was exactly what I needed, to show the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately what you want to achieve, to animate to `width: auto;`, can't be done using CSS only. You can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tAPsj/). This is due to this issue, that isn't only related to Firefox: [Bug 571344 - Support transitions to and from 'auto' values of left, top, width, height, etc.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=571344).

You can build a little JavaScript workaround, that will help you out here:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>Content 1 with more text</li>
    <li>Content 2</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul > li {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.55s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width 0.55s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: width 0.55s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: width 0.55s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.55s ease-in-out;
}
```

**JavaScript**

In this example I use the [jQuery](http://jquery.com) library. But it can also be done with [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com) very easily.

```
var elements = $('ul li');

elements.each(function(key, value) {
    var e = $(this)
    e.data('width-real', e[0].scrollWidth);
    e.data('width-collapsed', e.width());
});

elements.hover(
    function() {
        var e = $(this)
        e.css('width', e.data('width-real'));
    },
    function() {
        var e = $(this)
        e.css('width', e.data('width-collapsed'));
    }
);
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/TJ94M/)